# Lowest voltage applicable on AREF pin on Uno and Mega

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, adc, analog-sampling, analogreadresolution

I need to measure an Analog signal in the range of 5-30 mV.

Naturally, using the internal default 5V reference leads to very poor measurement resolution. I would like to use the capability to use an external reference voltage of 50mV on the AREF pin (using an Agilent precision power supply)

However, when I tried this in the lab, I noticed something strange. The ADC readout on the channel remained stuck at 1023. If I used anything above 0.5V on the AREF pin, the readout on the ADC is correct, and the counts reliably go up and down when I ramp up and down the Analog input accordingly.

Any idea how to resolve my issue?

Comment: Please tell us what your project is and where that signal comes from. Perhaps you need an opamp or external adc. The ads1115 has a gain (only x16), that might be enough.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) (page 375) the minimum voltage you are allowed to have as a reference voltage for the ADC is 1V.

Answer (score 0):

In the Arduino Mega it's possible to use differential mode between two analog pins with `10x` gain (or `200x`). But, the resolution is halved (`-512` ... `511`) as it's possible to measure negative difference. But with some precision voltage reference switching and `200x` gain you might be able to archieve some precision.

The downside is those `ADC` channels are not supported by `analogRead`, you have to do it directly by setting `ADMUX` register (or `ADMUX` and `ADCSRB`) to desired differential channel with gain.

```
byte backup = ADMUX; // store the arduino settings
ADMUX = _BV(REFS1) | _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX0); // internal 1.1V reference, differential: ADC1+ ADC0-, gain: 10x

// there should be some delay to stabilize the voltage reference (if another one was selected)
// but it's possible to preset it by  analogReference(INTERNAL1V1); in the setup() so no delay will be needed

ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC);  // start conversion

while ((ADCSRA & _BV(ADSC)) != 0);  // wait for conversion end (ADSC is cleared after the end by hardware)

int val = ADC; // read the result
ADMUX = backup; // restore original settings (from arduino)
```

In the Arduino everything else in ADC is configured and ADC is started, so just necessary changes are here. It should be working but I didn't tested it (I don't have the Arduino Mega here)

Comment: I am interested in differential measurements. Can you provide an example code?